# std::initializer_list type deduction

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, type-deduction, list-initialization

Recently I wrote a very simple class.

```
class C
{
public:
    void AddString(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const char*,int>> x)
    {
          //irrelevant
    }
};

int main()
 {
           C c;
           c.AddString({ {"1",1}, {"2", 2}, {"3", 3} });
           .... //other unimportant stuff
           return 0;
 }
```

To my pleasant surprise it compiled and worked correctly.  Can someone please explain to me how the compiler was able to deduce the nested braced initializers were for a `std::pair`? I am using MSVS 2013.

Answer (score 9):

```
c.AddString({ {"1",1}, {"2", 2}, {"3", 3} });
```

You're passing a *braced-init-list*, which itself contains nested *brace-init-list*s to `AddString`. The argument can match the `std::initializer_list<std::pair<const char*,int>>` parameter if the inner *braced-init-list*s can be converted to `std::pair<const char*,int>`.

This process of overload resolution occurs in two steps; first an attempt is made to match constructors of `std::pair` that take an `std::initializer_list` argument. Since [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) has no such constructor, the second step occurs, where the other constructors of `std::pair<const char*,int>` are enumerated with `char const[2]` and `int` as the arguments. This will match the following `pair` constructor because `char const[2]` is implicitly convertible to `char const *` and the constructor itself is not `explicit`.

```
template< class U1, class U2 >
constexpr pair( U1&& x, U2&& y );
```

---

Quoting N3337 *§13.3.1.7/1 [over.match.list]*

> When objects of non-aggregate class type `T` are list-initialized (8.5.4), overload resolution selects the constructor in two phases:
>   — Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors (8.5.4) of the class `T` and the argument list consists of the initializer list as a single argument.
>   — **If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class `T`** and the argument list consists of the elements of the initializer list.
>
> If the initializer list has no elements and `T` has a default constructor, the first phase is omitted. **In copy-list-initialization, if an `explicit` constructor is chosen, the initialization is ill-formed**.

Comment: Great answer, much more complete!

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies some things..I need to understand a little bit more about over load resolution when braced init lists are involved.

Comment: @pebbleonthebeach The rules for overload resolution when list-initialization is involved are what I copy-pasted above. If you meant you need to get familiar with overload resolution in general, I suggest you start with [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-Cpp-3-of-n) (watch the whole series if you can find the time).